# smtpClient only works on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I'm having a Send Mail function on my site. When debugging on localhost, everything works fine. But when site is published to the web, the SendMail-function returns this error message in the browser everytime i try to send a mail: "Your request timed out. Please retry the request."

Why does it work on localhost, but not on the live published website? What can be the issue?

Here is my code in my mvc-controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMail(HomeContentPage model)
    {
        const string username = "myMailAdress@gmail.com";
        const string password = "mySecretPassword";
        var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        var msg = new MailMessage();

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = loginInfo
        };

        string message = model.SendMail.SenderName + " have a message for you:<br /><br /><br />" + model.SendMail.Message
                         + "<br /><br />Avs. Phone: " + model.SendMail.Phone
                         +"<br /><br />Avs. Mail: " + model.SendMail.SenderAddress;
        var page = RavenSession.Load<ContentPage>(model.Id) as HomeContentPage;
        try
        {
            msg.From = new MailAddress("dwfff@hello.com", "MySite.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("myMailAdress@gmail.com"));
            msg.Subject = "MySite.com";
            msg.Body = message;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            smtpClient.Send(msg);

            page.SendMail.IsSuccess = true;
            page.Url = page.Url + "#contact";

            return View(page.Template.Name, page);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View(page.Template.Name, page);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the site being hosted..? also are you by chance storing any settings in a .config file..? do you have a system admin

Comment: @DJKRAZE The site is hosted at: https://www.citynetwork.se/ . I don't think I'm storing any mail-settings in a configfile, what type of settings would that be? //Thanks

Comment: does the hosted site support .NET..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE yes it supports .NET. The site is online. It's just the SendMail-function that doesn't work when site is online

Comment: ok out of curiosity can you show the using statement I wonder if you have a dependency issue

Comment: this should help you out .. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/sending-an-e-mail-using-Asp-Net-mvc/

Comment: Your outgoing SMTP connections may be firewalled out.  Have you checked it?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip How do I check that?

Comment: @DJKRAZE `using System.Net.Mail;` if that's what you mean?

Comment: is this MVC app or standard .NET app can you add some logging perhaps since you can't debug this remotely I take it ..

Comment: Do you have access to windows/unix shell at hosting server?  My experience is based on "full admin (root)" perspective.

Comment: here is another working example the only difference I see is how they use MailMessage Object and the To and From Email it differs from yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988348/error-in-sending-email-via-a-smtp-client

Comment: could there also be an issue with var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(username, password); did you try connecting manually to the email

Comment: also what about this `smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;`

Comment: I'm going to try out your proposed examples. I think it will take a while until these parts of my site will be republished and working online so I can test it // thanks

Comment: @DJKRAZE By add some logging. Do you mean the for example: the network tab in my chrome dev-tool whn I try to send a message? I'm getting a respone that the statusCode for sending is OK. But the message is never sent to the mail. It also takes almost 2 minutes waiting in the timing

Comment: no in code meaning in places where you thing errors may occur then start removing by process of elimination until you pinpoint the exact line of code or method call that of which is causing the error

Comment: @DJKRAZE I don't know how to do that. There are no errors as far as I can see. Where should I look for them?

Comment: you mean to tell me that you do not know how to add simple logging to your code..? how about adding some additional logging in the catch block and trying to capture the InnerText in regards to the Exception message..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE sorry I totally misunderstood what you were saying. I will try that

Comment: no problem . your logging can be anything from logging an entry to the `EventLog, Sql Server, TextFile, Console, etc...`