# Send mail fail c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm having problem trying to send a mail. VS give me a this error: Failure sending mail.
What i'm doing wrong!!

```
 string from = "from@htomail.com";
            string to = "to@gmail.com";
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from, "test", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = "testing";
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = "Loren ipsum";
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: `string to = "to@gmail.com";` ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @tnw I think he's changed it to that, as an example.

Comment: Your Host is `smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` and sending `from = "from@htomail.com";` What is the error message?

Comment: PS: setting smtp mail setting in web.config is the best way to go

Comment: @Sam I hope you're right!

Comment: @tnw Yeah, I hope so too; hopefully the password in `new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");` is actually "`password`".lol

Comment: I changed the mail address for a example address :)

Comment: @Freddy ...and the password too?

Comment: Show us the complpete stacktrace of the exception

Comment: @Sam Yeah!! it's just a example

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is not reading (and posting) the entire stacktrace of the exception...

Comment: There you can find why the exception is thrown...

Comment: @Shaharyar Say:smtpException was unhandled by user code

Comment: @Freddy lol, Good. Have you read/tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9201317/2246344)?

Comment: SSL port is 465, not 587, see if that works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this in your helper.cs

```
public static void SendEmail(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();
        emailMessage.From = new MailAddress("administrator@gmail.com", "Administrator");
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = message;
        emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        emailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        MailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("administrator@gmail.com", "p@ssw0rd123");
        MailClient.Send(emailMessage);
    }
```

Hope it helped