# inventory low and send mail in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, inventory

my project is supply chain managment and i want to send mail in asp.net when inventry is low then i want to send mail ...total inventory is 50...this is code which i done in submit button now in this submit button i also send mail when inventory is low ..how i done this

```
 b = inv.get_Inv(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_product.SelectedValue));

        d = inv.get_reorder(Convert.ToInt16(ddl_product.SelectedValue));
        if (b > 0 && b >= Convert.ToInt32(Txtquantity.Text))
        {
            c = b - Convert.ToInt32(Txtquantity.Text);
            saleorderid = 
            (DLL.ClassSales.addsales(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_customer.SelectedValue), 
                   Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate), 
              Convert.ToInt16(ddl_status.SelectedValue))).ToString();

            DLL.ClassSales.addsaleOrderDetail(Convert.ToInt16(saleorderid), 
          Convert.ToInt32(ddl_product.SelectedValue), 
             Convert.ToDecimal(Txtupprice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(Txtquantity.Text));

   DLL.ClassInventory.Update_inventory(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_product.SelectedValue), c);
        }
        if (c <= d)
        {  // alert and email (main menu pe jana chahiye)
            Response.Redirect("Purchases.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            //Label1.Text = "Inventory invalid";
        }
```

Comment: We don't know anything about this "inv" object, or enough about your code base to answer this question specifically.  But it looks like you could retrieve the current amount of a product that is in stock (is that what "b" is?  Those variable names are totally unhelpful), and then do an if statement to see if that amount is less than 50, and then call your email code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201317/1894151) show how you could send an email using C#.

Just remember to specify an STMP server that you have access to from your server. Your hosting provider might or might not supply this for you.

Comment: i know how to send mail but i dont know what condition i apply when inventory is less that 50 then send mail

Comment: Your question is misleading then. I guess your real question then is  how to determine the current inventory? I do not know about your system and the interface to it, so I cannot answer this directly. An educated guess would be, that you should be able to fetch it via a method call to DLL.ClassInventory.<something>(Convert.ToInt32(ddl_product.SelectedValue)) - If you use autocomplete in your editor, you might find a method from the list that resembles "getInventory" or similar?