# Why the message doesn't send to my outlook mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website for user to fill out information. After completed fill out information, the user click button to submit a ticket and send email to me as a copy. However, I didn't receive any email after I click to send it. The submit ticket was successful except the email. We use Microsoft Outlook.
Anyone know why or I am missing something?

I did add the reference `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

C# codes,

```
protected void BtnIPAM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //codes for submitting ticket then send email

    string uid = Bam.NEAt.GetUserID();

    try
    {
        //Create the Outlook application
        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        //Create the new message
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        //Add a recipient
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oMsg.Recipients.Add("xxxxx@xxxx.com");

        oRecip.Resolve();

        //Set the basic properties
        oMsg.Subject = "A Copy of IP Address Request";
        oMsg.Body = "This is a test who sent by " + uid;

        //Send the message
        oMsg.Save();
        oMsg.Send();

        oRecip = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oApp = null;

    }
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: Your empty `catch` block hides any error that might occur in the rest of the code. I'd suggest you remove it.

Comment: Did you install Outlook on your web server?

Comment: Why would you use Outlook on a server to send email?? You can just use a `MailMessage` object instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp for an example.

Comment: I had a case where sending to the same domain did not work correctly.. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Look at my answer, it is a better and more efficient method of sending an email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this to send an email:

```
    using System.Net;
    public static void SendAlertEmail()
    {
       System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
       message.To.Add("receive@whatever.com");
       message.Subject = "Put Subject";
       message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("sender@whatever.com");
       message.Body = "Body Message Here";
       System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
       smtp.Host = "put host settings here";
       smtp.Port = 25;
       smtp.EnableSsl = false;
       smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

To call it use this:

```
SendAlertEmail();
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatic send email from other email without require using password?

Comment: the answer I provided does not require a password.  Just make sure your host settings are correct.

Comment: try adding this: smtpt.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use Batch account and edit the correct host to make it work.