# Input form in ASP.NET MVC to PDF and then sent to an email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

I currently have a input form where the user can register to a website I have
created this form In MVC but NOT using razor but using the ASPX view engine
and for this reason I am unable to find examples which help. However, once the
user has completed the form I want the results from the form to be converted to
a pdf file and then that pdf file to be sent to a specific email address.

The input form is all done in HTML and CSS so I have only used InputBoxes such  as:

```
<input id="Name" type="text">
```

After a few more fields I have a submit button like:

```
<input id="Submit" type="submit">
```

I didn't include the full HTML code because its just repetition but if you would like
the full code let me know

I know doing this is quite extensive I probably first need to start with a 
PDF conversion tool but is there any other ways of doing this can someone direct me in the right direction?

Comment: you need to generate the pdf using a library, could be [itextpdf](http://itextpdf.com/) or [report.net](http://report.sourceforge.net/) (both of them should be available on nuget), then send the generated file using [smtp client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @YuliamChandra I have already had a look at itextpdf but I am not sure how to generate a pdf with it could you show me an example please if that's not too much to ask

Comment: [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12) is the online example..