# C# console application that sends a google calendar invitation

Tags: c#, email, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm a pretty new to C# and am much more familiar with Python.  But interfacing with a couple programs is more straightforward with C# so I'm attempting to do what I want with it instead of Python.

I've created a Python application that uses SMTP, but I would really like to leverage the Google Calendar API.  When I find C# code examples on how to write it, I'm confused as to what needs to be setup for it to work.  Where does the authorization come from?  A google app?

I would like a console application that can be run by another program which will send an email (or event invitation) to an Business Google account (in-house, co-workers).  I'm lost as to where I need to start.  What are the different things I need to accomplish this?  I'm confused about whether I need to make a Google App and how to navigate what is involved in authentication, or whether I even need it.  I didn't think authentication should be necessary except for the login in and password of the account I'm sending it from.  Some direction would be appreciated...

Further Edit:  Didn't know an iCal can accomplish an invite, most of the examples seemed to be for Outlook.  That might work.

But knowing I can set it up through the business account it superb, thanks...

Comment: Google Calendar invites are just iCal attachements. You can do this with just the SMTP client built into .NET and something like DDay.iCal package.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere - why do a down vote for someone asking for help?

Comment: @Tab not the downvoter, but if you look at the tool tip on the downvote it says "does not show research effort".  I think, as written, this question qualifies.

Comment: I'll clarify the question to show what I have looked at already.  But I thought a concise question would be more appreciate, I guess not...

Comment: @paqogomez - hmm - I guess I agree to some extent.  Sometimes it's hard to know where to start when just beginning.  Point taken.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make a Google app - if you have the account information for the Business account then you have the ability to use google's smtp server (your smtp server) to send email given that you have credentials - came concept as if you set up a desktop mail program to send and receive gmail.

Looks like this other stackoverflow question may help you out in the actual sending of the email:
[Send e-mail via SMTP using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp).
Here is another article that looks more step by step:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/65295-c-sending-email-through-smtp/

If it was me:
1. Get the credentials
2. Create .Net app to build and send an email - I would make the console app allow command line arguments as well.  DotNetPearls is a great site for quick reference and has an introduction to cmd line with C#: http://www.dotnetperls.com/main

Hope this helps - just happened to see the question and realized I have been down this road before

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is just what I needed.  Much appreciate the understanding.

Comment: Glad it helped. Not a problem.