# How to send email via c# SMTP

Tags: c#

I want to send email via C#, how i can do this by the correct way? I should use

```
System.Net.Mail
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
```

And now?

Comment: there is plenty of examples ,such  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp

Comment: Did you try to google your question?

Comment: or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mail.provider.com.br");
mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply@provider.com.br");
mail.To.Add("youremail@provider.com.br");
mail.Subject = "Some title";
mail.Body = "YOUR TEXT GOES HERE";
SmtpServer.Port = 'port';
//credentials
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremail@provider.com.br", "pa$$word");
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Just be aware that your post is code-only (and is answered for sure before). If you decide to answer, at least try to put some more effort in.