# How to send email in windows 10 apps using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I am working on a Windows 10 store app project. In my project I need to send confirmation email to client using my app. How can I do it without using any confirmation dialogue to show to user?

Confirmation email is like

```
"You order no "xy" has been confirmed."
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Do you want to connect to some kind of smtp server and send mail?

Comment: FWIW, I googled your question title and the first result was an MSDN article updated for UWP apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send e-mail via SMTP using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: To share content on WinRT, you have to use DataTransferManager. If you want prepare a mail and let user send it, you can use a snippet like :

    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:test@mail.com?subject=my email subject&body=my email body"));

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Net.Mail;

...

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("you@yourcompany.com", "user@hotmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.google.com";
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

reference: [Send email with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Also as mentioned in the comments see this : [MSDN Docs Send Email](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269391.aspx)

Comment: System.Net.Mail  namespace is not found

Comment: What .NET version are u if I may ask?