# C# email not getting sent SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, email, smtp

I am trying to send email programmatically in C# but I don't find what I am missing. Here is the code for the same

```
string SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body, string senderID)
        {
            string result = "Message Sent Successfully..!!";
            const string senderPassword = "mypassword";
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                    Timeout = 30000,
                };
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, subject, body);
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
            catch (SmtpException e)
            {
                result = "Smtp status code " + e.StatusCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result ="Error sending email " +ex.ToString();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I have tried seeing the value inside result variable its has two value

1. Smtp status code General Failure
2. The operation has timed out// If we comment the code catch (SmtpException e)

If I look in to the msdn website for SMTP status code "General failure" [smtp status code interpretation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)  we will find that the status code means the host cannot be found and I tried doing nslookup and the host "smtp.gmail.com" is available and accessible from telnet.

What I am missing in the program?

Comment: Related [Send e-mail via SMTP using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for sending mail programmatically using c#. it is working fine in my machine.

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("email");
        mail.To.Add("email");
        mail.Subject = "Subject";
        mail.Body = "Message";
        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "false";
    }
```

Comment: If we catch you exception we get "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: i guess you need to change settings in your gmail account.

Comment: I have turned on the less secure app setting in my gmail still it didn't help

Comment: well your code is working perfectly fine on my machine.

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar remove second verification code in your gmail account and check given username and password is correct one?. reference : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection1

Answer (score 0):

```
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   mail.From = new MailAddress("frommail", "fromText");
   mail.To.Add(toEMailId);
   mail.Subject = "TestSubject";
   mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
   mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
   mail.Body = "Test mailBody";
   //SMTPServer
   SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("yourSMTPServer");
   //SMTPPort
   SmtpServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32("PostNumber");
   SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   //Set SMTP Username and Password
   SmtpServer.Credentials = new             System.Net.NetworkCredential("SMTPUserName","SMTPPassword");
  //EnableSSL
  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
  SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, you can try.

```
public static bool SendEmail(string subject, MailAddress from, List<string> to,List<string> cc, string body, Attachment attachment)
{
    try
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.From = from;
        foreach (var item in to)
            mail.To.Add(item);
        foreach (var item in cc)
            mail.CC.Add(item);
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = body;
        if (attachment != null)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
        mailClient.Port = 587;//maybe 25
        mailClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
        mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("EmailAddress", "EmailPassword");
        //mailClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("a@gmail.com", "1234");


        try
        {
            mailClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```