# Sending files through asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I cannot send email with this code, my label showed 'failure sending mail'. Pls help me. yemail = sender's email. Email = recepient's email. emailp = Sender's Password

```
    using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

protected void end_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress(yemail.Text, "Sender's Name");
    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(Email.Text));
    msg.Subject = Subject.Text;
    msg.Body = Message.Text;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));

    }

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(yemail.Text, emailp.Text);
    Label1.Visible = true;
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(msg);
        Label1.Text = "Email Send successfully";

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: May you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: When you get an exception, don't just read it's Message, also inspect any `.InnerException`s, they may contain the "real" issue. You can use the debugger to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your gmail configuration is ok. Click [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and chose "Open".

And add port to your codes as this;

```
    smp.Port = 587;
    smp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: It has a new error it says 'Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated' Pls help :(

Comment: I have made a new comment.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the account settings, locate the SMTP request in its **Recent activity**, and select "**This was me**":

[image]