# How to configure SMTP for webmail

Tags: c#, smtpclient, webmail

I have tried setting SMTP configuration for my webmail. I have used following settings for configuration

```
Username:   xyz@mydomain.in
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    a2plcpnl0234.prod.iad2.secureserver.net
                    IMAP Port: 993
                    POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server:    a2plcpnl0234.prod.iad2.secureserver.net
                    SMTP Port: 465
```

When I tried with these settings I get time out error/Failure sending mail.
Below is the c# code

```
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "webmail.mydomain.in";
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
  credentials.UserName = "xyz@mydomain.in";
  credentials.Password = "mypasword";
  smtp.Credentials = credentials;
  smtp.Port = 465;
```

Answer (score 0):

If time out is the issue then add

```
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Timeout = 1200000;
```

mostly it will fix the issue

Updated as per the comment

[Please refer the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp)

Comment: for gmail SMTP its working without timeout.If I use above settings its showing errors.I think problem with settings.So is there any mistake in above configuration

Comment: @veenahosur I have added a link in my answer please go through it.But the key is debugging and finding what is the real issue