# Send email from bot framework FormFlow

Tags: botframework

I have an example bot created using FormFlow:

```
public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
        {
            OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<SandwichOrder> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
            {
                await context.PostAsync("We are currently processing your sandwich. We will message you the status.");
            };

            return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
                        .Message("Welcome to the sandwich order bot!")
                        .Field(nameof(Sandwich))
                        .Field(nameof(Length))
                        .Field(nameof(Bread))
                        .Field(nameof(Cheese))
                        .AddRemainingFields()
                        .Message("Thanks for ordering a sandwich!")
                        .OnCompletion(processOrder)
                        .Build();
    }
```

On completion of form, the control comes at:

```
OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<SandwichOrder> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("We are currently processing your sandwich. We will message you the status.");
                };
```

I want to send an email to myself with all the form fields. How can I connect with SMTP and write an email function to send an email with all selected options and inputs from user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not related to `Botframework`, it's only "how to send an email from C#".

You have several options, like:

- using SendGrid
- using `SMTPClient` (have a look here for example: [Send e-mail via SMTP using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201239/send-e-mail-via-smtp-using-c-sharp))
- using Graph API if you use Office 365 accounts (or on premises but it depends on the configuration etc.)
- using EWS (Exchange Web Services)
- other ways...

The fields that you want to put in your email are contained in the `state` variable