# how to send an email from a microsoft bot?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I developed a chatbot and deployed it on skype. I have one new thing to be added to bot.

If a user requests for a office cab in bot then bot has to take user input(like destination, emp-name, etc) and send an email to a particular mail ID(outlook).

So my question is:

- **How to trigger an email from Bot?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use SendGrid.
Here with example code.

```
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
             SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sendgrid.net");

             mail.From = new MailAddress("youremailaddress@gmail.com");
             mail.To.Add(useremail);
             mail.Subject = "";
             mail.Body ="";

             SmtpServer.Port = 587;
             SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("apikey", "");
             SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

             SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

References: [How to make my bot send an e-mail to a given email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847791/how-to-make-my-bot-send-an-e-mail-to-a-given-email-address)

Comment: Just to add, SendGrid is a third party service but it does have a listing in the Azure Resource catalog. Start there and it should walk you through the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Email Skill from Bot Framework:

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/samples/email/